# Changing thickness line using pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

Changing thickness line using `pst-solides3d`:

I'm trying to draw a thinness line in space using `pst-solides3d`:

```
\begin{center}
\psset{unit=0.4cm}
\psset[pst-solides3d]{viewpoint=40 30 25 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,fontsize=0}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(3,10)
\defFunction[algebraic]{paraboloid1}(r,t){r*cos(t)}{2*r*sin(t)}{r^2}
\psSolid[algebraic,object=surfaceparametree,base=0 2 pi 2 div 3 pi mul 2 div,linewidth=0.5pt,function=paraboloid1,ngrid=20 25,linecolor=blue,incolor=Turquoise]%
\psSolid[object=line,args=0 4 0 0 4 4,linewidth=0.1pt]
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
```

but command `linewidth` seems have no effect. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature that now forms part of the standard release of `pst-solides3d`.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
\psPoint(0, 4, 0){A}\psPoint(0, 4, 4){B}
\psline[linewidth=2pt](A)(B)
```

I'll fix it in `pst-solides3d.pro` that linewidth is taken into account for
the `object=line`. The updated package is available for TeX Live and also 
MiKTeX.